# UITableView height is not changing in run time by button action with SnapKit

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, snapkit

When I try to change the height of the table view am getting the following error in console.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000014e40c0@AddTravellerViewController.swift#49 UITableView:0x7ff246001200.height == 60.0>",
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000014e5860@AddTravellerViewController.swift#49 UITableView:0x7ff246001200.height == 120.0>" )
```

UIButton action: I am loading this function in viewdidload for first time. from second time onwards it's printing the above error message.

```
func addButtonAction(){

    travellersCount! += 1
    tableHeight! += 60

    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(self.view).offset(10)
        make.right.equalTo(self.view).offset(-10)
        make.top.equalTo(self.view).offset(120)
        make.height.equalTo(tableHeight!)
    }

    addButotn.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
        make.height.equalTo(40)
        make.top.equalTo(tableView.snp.bottom).offset(10)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

TableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return travellersCount!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Textcell", for: indexPath) as! TextfieldTableViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you've already declared a height constraint for your `UITableView` through `SnapKit`'s `makeConstraints` method and your `addButtonAction()` supposedly gets called more than once to keep 'creating' conflicting height constraints with greater values

Well, the `viewDidLoad` usually doesn't get called more than once, but it's better not to assume that and do your one-time configurations inside it. If you're instantiating from a nib file, consider doing this inside `awakeFromNib`...

Now, to solve this inside `viewDidLoad`:-

1) If you want this to be a one-time process, you could create a property( of type `Constraint`, which is SnapKit's custom object-type) to hold a reference of the height constraint which you declare inside `tableView.snp.makeConstraints` and do a nil check:

Delcare a property above:

```
private var tableViewHeightConstraint: Constraint?
```

and do a nil check:

```
tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.equalTo(self.view).offset(10)
    make.right.equalTo(self.view).offset(-10)
    make.top.equalTo(self.view).offset(120)

    if self.tableViewHeightConstraint == nil {
       self.tableViewHeightConstraint = make.height.equalTo(tableHeight!)
    }
}
```

2) Or, if you'd like to update the height every time( as you're incrementing `tableHeight` by 60 ), you could make use of `updateConstraints`:

```
tableView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
    //Update your height constraint here. Note: This will keep increasing the height of your table on every call
    make.height.equalTo(tableHeight!)
}
```

(You might have to call `layoutIfNeeded()` after this, for the changes to take place)

I haven't tested this code but this should do it for you. If not, let me know...

Answer (score 0):

set heightForRow `UITableView.automaticDimension` it will set height of row automatic according to the content.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Irrelevant to the question asked.